# Elastic search API facets

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I want to implement facets using the elastic search API facets. I tried and am getting the error

I have data in the format

```
{
     field1:"data",
     field2 :{
                       innerField1 : "data2",
                      innerField2: "data3"
                 }
}
```

i want to implement the facets with search API, to get the different innerField2 and their count.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          // query
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "innerField2": [
      {
        "type": "value",
        "name": "innerField2",
        "sort": { "count": "desc" },
        "size": 10
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

i want to know how to pass the facets properly to get the facets info.

as am getting the error

```
"error": {
                    "root_cause": [
                        {
                            "type": "parsing_exception",
                            "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [facets].",
                            "line": 1,
                            "col": 133
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "parsing_exception",
                    "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [facets].",
                    "line": 1,
                    "col": 133
                },
                "status": 4
```

document following: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/facets.html

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you are referencing is for the [App Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/index.html). App Search runs on top of Elasticsearch and has a different API.

You're probably looking for the [Elasticsearch Aggregations API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html), and more specifically the [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

```
POST your-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          // query
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "innerField2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field.innerField2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this return the results and facets info also?
I want a similar result as this example.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/facets-guide.html.

They were able to get facets and results using the above API

Comment: My field is a text field, not a keyword so i can't use  eggs on keyword field

Comment: You can create a keyword sub-field in order to make it work.